# Best way to essentially make an overridden constant variable?

Tags: c++, variables, overriding, member

I want to make something functionally similar to this:

```
   class Base
   {
       public:
           const int ClassID = 1;
   }

   class Derived1 : public Base
   {
       public:
           const int ClassID = 2;
   }

   class Derived2 : public Base
   {
       public:
           const int ClassID = 3;
   }
```

But, obviously, you can't override variables. What would be the best way to achieve the same functionality?

*(The context for this is a video game where there are different troops, overridden from the same parent "BaseTroop" class. I want each troop to have its own ID that can be retrieved from anywhere)*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ID is per instance or per class?

Comment: Per class. Each class has its own ID.

Comment: You might give `Base` a (protected) constructor that takes an *id*, defaulting to the base-class *id* (e.g. 1). Use that to initialize the constant `ClassId` variable in the instance. Then `Derived1`'s constructor calls `Base(2)` .. right now you're creating a distinct `ClassId` variable in `Derived1` and hiding the base-class variable, rather than changing the value.

Comment: Do you really need to override it, or just give it a different value for different derived types?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the default member initialiser in derived classes.

But, there is no need to rely on the default initialiser. You can provide an initialiser in the constructor:

```
struct Derived1 : Base
{
    Derived1(): Base{2} {}
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
    Derived2(): Base{3} {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a virtual function, returning the ID. You can also have a `static` variable or function returning the same ID, in case you want to get it without a class instance. You can also assign the IDs automatically, using CRTP:

```
#include <iostream>

struct BaseLow
{
    virtual int GetId() const = 0;
    virtual ~BaseLow() {}
};

namespace impl
{
    int &GetIdCounter()
    {
        static int ret = 0;
        return ret;
    }
}

template <typename Derived>
struct Base : BaseLow
{
    inline static const int id = impl::GetIdCounter()++;

    int GetId() const override final
    {
        return id;
    }
};

struct Derived1 : Base<Derived1> {};
struct Derived2 : Base<Derived2> {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Derived1::id << '\n'; // 0
    std::cout << Derived2::id << '\n'; // 1

    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    BaseLow *ptrs[] = {&d1, &d2};

    for (BaseLow *ptr : ptrs)
        std::cout << ptr->GetId() << '\n'; // 0, 1
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason why you wouldn't just be able to have a member variable in the base class, then in your derived class, change it? Is that possible?

Comment: @Samathan It's possible, but IMO wasteful (a copy of ID for each instance) and error-prone (can accidentally change the ID).